# ListPicker with loaded selected items is not updated

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have one form for creating and editing items. One part of form is this ListPicker:

```
    <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="categoryList" SelectionMode="Multiple" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" CacheMode="BitmapCache">
    </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Backend code for ListPicker:

```
public ItemsPage()
{
       InitializeComponent();
       categoryList.ItemsSource = Categories;
       this.categoryList.SummaryForSelectedItemsDelegate += SumarizeItems;
}


private string SumarizeItems(IList items)
{

      if (items != null && items.Count > 0)
      {
          string summarizedString = "";
          for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
          {
             summarizedString += (string)items[i];

            // If not last item, add a comma to seperate them
            if (i != items.Count - 1)
                summarizedString += ", ";
          }

          categoryList.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
          return summarizedString;
      }
      else
      {
          categoryList.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
          return "...";
       }
}
```

If I am creating a new object on the page, ListPicker works fine.
If I go to the page in editing mode, load selected values in OnNavigatedTo() method

```
categoryList.ItemsSource = Categories;
categoryList.SelectedItems = edited_object.Categories;
```

Selected categories are correctly loaded but if I change them in full mode of ListPicker, ListPicker is not updated and shows original values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because full mode of `ListPicker` is a different page, so it's trigger `OnNavigatedTo()` event right after user finished selecting items, right before `ListPicker`'s `SelectedItems` changed to the new selection.

Simple solution to avoid reverting user selection is by checking if navigation mode is `Back` (this is the navigation mode triggered by `ListPicker` full mode to go back to your editing page) :

```
if (e.NavigationMode != NavigationMode.Back)
{
    categoryList.ItemsSource = Categories;
    categoryList.SelectedItems = edited_object.Categories;
}
```

Comment: @Eldho Glad to know that the answer helped more people :)